# jQuery - enable ajax browser-caching only for scripts

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, caching

During inserting html into some elements:

```
someElement.html(someHTML);
```

someHTML can contain script tags. jQuery loads theese scripts via ajax. But scripts are loading whith time parameter:

```
../script.js?_=1473975228450
```

which disables the static script browser-caching. I can set global setting for enable ajax browser-cache:

```
$.ajaxSetup({cache:true});
```

But it doesn't insert time in non-static requests too.

Can I enable jQuery ajax browser-caching only by filemask (for example *.js), or only for `<script>` tags, injected with .html() ?

Comment: would have to use `beforeSend` callback to modify url

Comment: @charlietfl no, thanks. Global beforeSend callback - it is sollve of problem.

Comment: not saying it is but you could leave the global cache alone and remove the timestamp from `.js` files only that way

Comment: Consider injecting current date/time as a parameter (manually) for asset loads you want to escape cache. Ie, `/* allow cache */ $.ajaxSetup({cache:true}); /* cached load */ someElement.load(asset_url); /* defeat caching */ var epochSeconds = new Date().getTime() / 1000; someOtherElement.load(asset_url + '?_=epochSeconds);`

Comment: @Jeromy French thanks, but i have a project with 100+ dynamic ajaxRequests definitions, i wouldn't insert the parameter in each of theese..

Comment: Can you create a plnkr http://plnkr.co to demonstrate issue?